# Visual Studio 2022 try to connect to sql server instead of connection history, Getting error "'CONNECTIONPROPERTY' is not a recognized

Tags: visual-studio

Getting error "'CONNECTIONPROPERTY' is not a recognized

This is the new problem I have in VS 2022 it works fine in VS 2019

The same, issue is happening with Visual Studio 2022. It works fine with VS 2019.

The connections/ login window looks like in SQL Server Management Studio.

Details: in Visual Studio on the SQL Server Object Explorer I was able to add the PDW server.

I can browse the server tables, stored procedures, security and all.

If I right-click on a database, or table and select "New Query", it will ask me to log in with the same window as M Studio.

I am able to connect fine if I open an existing query.DSQL file it allows me to use history connections or connect normally.

So I am connected to the server on SQL Server Object Explorer but when try to open a stored procedure it asks to login again and that is where it fails because it tries to connect with different parameters

I get this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYcFr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYcFr.png)
instead of (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0beik.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0beik.png)

when I add the server I am able to brose the databases table and so on when try to open query window
it ask you to connect when was already connected.
the error is related that it try to connect like management studio that does not allow connection to PDW.
then I do have a different window see the pictures

Comment: I've got a similar issue, have you figured it out?